# Show there exists finite set $X$ and an injective group homomorphism $\phi:G\to Sym(X)$ where $G$ is a finite group.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I am working through a set of problems and a question states:

> (1) Let $G$ be finite. Show that there exists a finite set $X$ and an injective group homomorphism
> $\rho:G\rightarrow Sym(X)$, where $Sym(X)$ denotes the group of bijections from $X$ to itself.
>
> (2) Let $\Gamma$ be the symmetry group of all isometries of the regular octahedron, and
> let $X$ be the set of eight faces of the octahedron. Show that $\Gamma$ acts transitively on $X$,
> describe the stabilizer of an element of $X$, and hence find the order of $Γ$.
>
> (3) The action of $\Gamma$ on $X$ yields an injective homomorphism from $\Gamma$ to $Sym(X)$. By
> numbering the faces of the octahedron from $1$ to $8$ we can identify $Sym(X)$ with $S_8$, and hence we obtain a homomorphism $\phi: \Gamma\to S_8$. Is the image $\phi(\Gamma)$ of $\Gamma$ a normal subgroup of $S_8$?

I have completed the first 2 parts. For (3) I have an idea but I'm not convinced.

The image is a normal subgroup if and only if given $x\in \Gamma$, $\sigma\in S_8$ we can find $z\in \Gamma$ such that $\sigma \phi(x)\sigma^{-1}=\phi(z)$. Obviously then I could answer the question via listing each type of isometry and seeing if I can find a corresponding $z$, however I don't think the question actually requires me to do this. Any hints would be great

Comment: As it is stated, for (1) I would agree with you (Cayley's embedding).

Comment: It is not true that the stabilizer of each element of $X$ is trivial. You are told in the problem that the size of $X$ is $8$. I am not sure if I should be encouraging you to do this, but you could try searching for "symmetry group octahedron".

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you both I have edited the question now. If you have any hints for (3) that would be great! This is a question where I dont believe I need to fully list the set of symmetries of anything like that at any point

Comment: It isn't normal in  $S_8$, so you just have to find a single $x \in \Gamma$ and $\sigma \in S_8$ such that $\sigma \phi(x) \sigma^{-1} \not\in \phi(\Gamma)$.